# Second ajax call return 404

Tags: ajax

My second ajax call starts only when the first succeeded. The problem, the second ajax call return 404 error code. Find below the code.

Can anyone help troubleshooting ? Thanks a lot

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/transaction/status/'+$("#telephone").val()+'/'+$("#transref").val(),
    dataType : 'json',
    cache: false,

    error: function(xhr,error,textStatus){
    console.log(error);
  },

    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      if(data.transfertResponseCode == '01'){
        $('#statut').empty();$('#statut').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div><div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">Transaction en cours de traitement.... Veuillez patienter quelques instants</div></div>');

      }else if(data.transfertResponseCode == '00'){

        var data = {"msisdn":$("#telephone").val(), "amount":$("#montant").val(), "transref":$("#transref").val(), "clientid":$("#clientID").val()};

        $.ajax({
          contentType: 'application/json',
          url: 'http://74.208.84.251:8221/QosicBridge/user/deposit',
          type: 'POST',
          data : JSON.stringify(data),
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,

          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa('USR28' + ":" + 'YG739G5XFVPYYV4ADJVW'));
          },

          error: function(xhr,error,textStatus){
          console.log(error);
        },

          complete: function(data) {},

             success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
            }
        });                                     
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: did you check your  `data` have all value in it ,i.e: nothing is `null` before sending it to second ajax request , also i suggest you to change `data` to some other name .

Comment: I confirm nothing dis null. Let me update data by other name and give you feedback